# How do I change the color in List simple_list_item_multiple_choice

Tags: android

Hi I have a list with simple_list_item_multiple_choice layout. The list is all in white and my background is also white and hence it is not visible. How do I change the color for that??

Thanks,
Prerna

Answer (score 1):

It does seem rather foolish for the api to lack such basic functionality, but I think you solution will have to be to define your own `ListAdapter`:

XML:

```
<android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#rrggbb"
/>
```

Custom List Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, items));
}
```

If you run into problems based on the state of the list item (disabled/selected/clicked etc) you'll have to set the `android:listSelector` to a custom selector which is made up of a collection of `StateListDrawable`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_disabled" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" />
</selector>
```